# How to sort multi-column lists by first or second column in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, array

I have a list with two-segment.

```
var list = ee.List([
  [101, 102],
  [102, 103],
  [103, 104],
  [106, 100],
  [104, 105],
  [105, 106],
  ])
```

How can sort this list by first or second column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You strip off of the column you want to sort by, then use it as the "keys" argument to list.sort.

```
var sortColumn = 0;
var keyValues = list.map(function(inner) {
    return ee.List(inner).get(sortColumn)
})
var sorted = list.sort(keyValues)
```

Comment: i am grateful, thank you very much. I think, you can implement this function to work with arrays and lists in GEE. Thank you very much, dear Noel

Comment: Dear Noel, your code is worked, but if the list has same two elements, this code does not display it, it display distinct of list, not all of the list, for example; if list is :  <br/> var list = ee.List([
  [101, 102],
  [102, 103],
  [103, 104],
  [106, 100],
  [104, 105],
  [105, 106],
  [101, 102],
  [102, 103],
  [103, 104] 
  ])   it display 6 elements again

Comment: You are correct; that's a bug in the list.sort method.  I've filed a bug report and started on a fix.