# How to handle empty filter results in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to filter a country border feature by countryname from GAUL_0 dataset.

When i change CountryName to "Turkey", this code works and draw Country border on the map.

But when i changed is for an undefined country, like below example, it does not print an error message.

How can i control or handle empty filter results?

```
var CountryName = "1Turkey"
var Gaul_0 = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level0")
var filtered0 = Gaul_0.filter(ee.Filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME',CountryName)))

print (filtered0)

if (filtered0!==null ) {
Map.addLayer(filtered0)
}
else
{
 print('undefined')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle it on the client side, you only have to replace

```
if (filtered0!==null ) {
```

for

```
if (filtered0.size().getInfo() > 0 ) {
```

But sooner or later you'll need to handle it on the server side. Then, you'll need to use the function `ee.Algorithms.If` on the size of the filtered collection.

```
var result = ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), true, false)
```

Don't forget to cast the result. For example:

```
var result = ee.String(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), 'true', 'false'))
```

I leave you here a working example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ce0a9912f58afafb8b449636240464e0

Comment: Thank you very much, Rodrigo... Could you please take a look this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/402355/how-to-make-a-linked-list-with-repeated-values-in-google-earth-engine

Comment: Any idea why `ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size())` seems to work but `ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size()>0)` does not?

Comment: `filtered.size()` is computed on the server side, and the conditional `>0` is checked on the client side. I think that is the problem.